# concatenate 2 readed files python

Tags: python, hex, concatenation

I was trying to generate all the hex numbers from `0000000000` to `FFFFFFFFFF` with all combinations on 10 length string but the file size it was very large, so i think to divide in two lists from `00000` to `fffff` and then join that lists through `stdout` and pipe it to aircrack

The code:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- encode: utf-8
import sys

def main():

    fd = open("hexdic.txt", "r")
    ffdd = open("dichex.txt","r")
    for line in fd.readlines():

            for otra in ffdd.readlines():
                    print line.replace("\n","") + otra.replace("\n","")

    fd.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the issue is when the file take the first line on the first file "00000" and run all the other lines on the second file from "00000" to "FFFFF" the program finish instead to continue with "00001" from the first list and run all the second list.

why?

well i think to use regex to generate random combinations.

Can you help me with my code showing me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Dont use `readlines()`. It's better to use `with` and `for line in fd:`. `readlines()` reads the entire line in memory. There is no need for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your main function as below
def main():

```
fd = open("hexdic.txt", "r")
for line in fd.readlines():
        ffdd = open("dichex.txt","r")
        for otra in ffdd.readlines():
                print line.replace("\n","") + otra.replace("\n","")
        ffdd.close()
fd.close()
```

Comment: the values on the files are the same

root@fedora:~# head hexdic.txt 
00000
00001
00002
00003
00004
00005
00006
00007
00008
00009

i cut the 0x at the start of the string

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to read the hex values from files? How about

`for i in xrange(0xFFFFFFFFFF):
    print '%010x' % i`